# Recover from a method throwing an exception

Tags: java, exception

I am fairly new to java esp. to some of the coding practices. I have a situation where a method throws a `NullPointerException` and the calling method catches it.

```
try {
    String test = Class.method(arg)
}    
catch (Exception ex) {
    ...
}

public String method(arg){
String str;
...
if(str == null) throw(exception)
return str;
}
```

Now some method inside `Class.method(arg)` throws a `NullPointerException` and it gets caught in the above catch (like above). Instead I want to do something like:

```
if (test == null) { do something else }
```

inside the try block.

What is the best way to handle this? Can I remove the throw inside method and make it return null?

Comment: Is test null, or did something else cause the exception?

Comment: Yes. There is a test for null in one of the methods and hence it throws the exception directly.

Comment: @SairamSankaran the method shouldn't do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should catch Exception in `method(arg)` and return `null` incase of any exception.

Sample Program:

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            String test = method("1");
            if(test==null){
                //do something else
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

    }

    private static String method(String str) throws Exception{
            if(str.equals("1")) return null;
            else if(str.equals("2")) throw new Exception("My Exception");
            else return str;          
    }

}
```

Now you can change method to something like this, it all depends on your requirement:

```
    private static String method(String str) throws Exception{
        try{
            if(str.equals("1")) return null;
            else if(str.equals("2")) throw new Exception("My Exception");
            else return str;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes. The exception is getting caught and sent to log. But I want to act on it. So instead of the inside method throwing the exception, I want to do something else if method(arg) returns null

Comment: if method() returns null, you can have a if statement to do something else. I didn't understood the problem here.

Comment: OK. The method directly throws exception instead of returning null. But i want to handle the null outside the method.

Comment: This is exactly I am looking for. I have jus t this [if(str.equals("2")) throw new Exception("My Exception");] in my method. Can I remove this and replace it as [if(str.equals("1")) return null;]. I am not sure what is the advantage of throwing the exception inside the method

Comment: its just an example, not a real life programming scenario. I am explicitly throwing exception to show the different ways to use it. You can do anything with this based on your requirements.

Comment: This is where my doubt is. The programmer has caught the null inside the method and throwing it. Instead I want to return the null and handle it in my try block. SO I want to know what are the adv/disadv of throwing the exception inside the method instead of returning null.

Comment: Throwing exception is important to send the proper message to the calling party to debug the issue. If you will just send null, the caller will have no idea of the exception.

Comment: So how should I handle this. I want to replace your second if with your first if.

Comment: you can change it according to your needs, please select as correct if you are satisfied with the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Expecting a null pointer exception has some bad smell. Wouldn't it be possible to add a null test in `method` and return the agreed result without waiting for an exception?

So instead of

```
 public String method(String arg) {
   try {
     return arg.toString();
   } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
     return null;
   }
 }
```

you really should do

```
 public String method(String arg) {
   if (arg == null) {
     return null;
   }

   return arg.toString();
 }
```

a considerable alternative would be throwing an exception other then NPE to give a hint to the problem - and because returning `null` is usually a bad idea:

```
 public String method(String arg) {
   if (arg == null) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Passing null is illegal");
   }

   return arg.toString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    Class.method(arg);
} catch ( NullPointerException npe ) {
    //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify a catch clause for the `NullPointerException` in particular:

```
try {
    String test = Class.method(arg)
}
catch (NullPointerException ex) {
    // test == null
    // do something
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // ?
}
```

But you might not want to put too much logic/behavior in the `catch` clause, so consider just putting an `if` block like the one you suggested outside the `try-catch` block:

```
try {
    String test = Class.method(arg)
}
catch (NullPointerException ex) {
    // At least log the exception; never swallow exceptions. NEVER.
    System.out.println(ex);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // ?
}
if(test != null) {
    // do something
}
else {
    // do something else
 }
```